# Magento 2.1, Customer-Login - User stay Logged In

Tags: magento-2.1, login

Users "Stay Logged In" in Magento 2.1, they should never be automatically Logged Out. Manual Log Out only.

Comment: It's default installation? if yes, can you share your 'session.gc_maxlifetime' from ini?

Comment: Yes Sohal, its a default installation and session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 not have auto logout setting for fronend

But

We have **Cookie Lifetime** for frontend setting.

**System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Cookie Settings -> Cookie Lifetime**

increase these if that was low.